# JDBC inserting variables to database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, sql-insert

I'm passing my method `InsertQuery` variables from another method which are entered by the user via `Scanner`.

How do I fill in the `iName`, `iType` etc. into my `iQuery` so that I can insert them into my DB?

```
public void InsertQuery (String iName, String iType, int health_Problem, Date date2, String aRemind, String docName, String docType, String docAdress)
{
    final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ehealthdb?serverTimezone=UTC";
    final String DBUSER = "root";
    final String DBPSWD = "root";
    
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,DBUSER,DBPSWD);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        
        String iQuery = "INSERT into appointment" 
                        + "(ID, PatientID, Insurance_Name, Insurance_Type, Health_Problem, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Remind, Doctor_Name,Doctor_Type,Doctor_Adress)"
                        + "values ('1','1',,'Gesetzlich','5','15.01.2020','1 Week','Musterarzt','Hausarzt','Musterstraße')";
        
        stmt.executeUpdate(iQuery);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong @InsertQuery");
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider a PreparedStatement.

Comment: also consider this code leaks the database connection. using try-with-resources like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534142/217324) will fix that. also follow the exception handling advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534143/217324).

Comment: By the way, `Date` is a terrible class that was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Furthermore, appointments should be represented not as a moment, in case politicians change time zone's offset. Better to store `LocalDateTime` via `PreparedStatement#setObject`, and `ZoneId` as text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably be to use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
public void insertQuery
     (String iName, String iType, int healthProblem, Date date2, String aRemind, String docName, String docType, String docAddress)
     throws SQLException {

    final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ehealthdb?serverTimezone=UTC";
    final String DBUSER = "root";
    final String DBPSWD = "root";

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,DBUSER,DBPSWD);
         PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
                 "INSERT into appointment" +
                         "(ID, PatientID, Insurance_Name, Insurance_Type, Health_Problem, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Remind, Doctor_Name, Doctor_Type, Doctor_Adress) " +
                         "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        stmt.setString(1, iName);
        stmt.setString(2, iType);
        stmt.setInt(3, healthProblem);
        stmt.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(date2.getTime()));
        stmt.setString(5, aRemind);
        stmt.setString(6, docName);
        stmt.setString(7, docType);
        stmt.setString(8, docAddress);

        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println("Something went wrong @InsertQuery");` inside `catch` block, I suggest using `e.printStackTrace();` so that the programmer can get to know the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive Personally, I'd just throw the exception upwards and let a part of the program with more context deal with it intelligently, but TBH, I just copied the `catch` block from the OP, as it's not the focus of this question

Comment: @Mureinik a _ton_ of confusion in those new to java programming (source: Lots of things, including StackOverflow questions) arise from bad exception handling. Examples, blogs, and SO answers are perpetuating this error. I think it is time we as a community step up and start the hard work on eliminating this confusion. I hope you agree and start fixing catch blocks even if the question isn't about it, especially if it's fairly obvious it's a newish java programmer asking.

Comment: @Mureiknik and yes, of course - throwing that exception onwards is clearly the right move here. The method is named `insertQuery`, SQL is baked into its very definition, thus `throws SQLException` is warranted, no?

Comment: @rzwitserloot yeah, I guess that would be the responsible thing to do. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is to use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which solves the following two important problems apart from many other benefits:

1. It helps you protect your application from [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
2. You will not have to enclose the text values within single quotes yourself.

Typical usage is as shown below:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO appointment(ID, PatientID, Insurance_Name, Insurance_Type, Health_Problem) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    //...
    
    pstmt.setString(1, id);
    pstmt.setString(2, patientId);
    pstmt.setString(3, insuranceName);
    //...

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that for each `?`, you will have to use `pstmt.setXXX`. Another thing you need to understand is that in the method call, `pstmt.setString(1, Id)`, `1` refers to the first `?` and not the first column in your table.

**Some other important points:**

1. I have used try-with-resources statement which is an easier and recommended way to close the resources after the program is finished with it. Learn more about it from [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on it.
2. Always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. `Insurance_Name` should be named as `insuranceName`.

Comment: it might help to highlight the use of the try-with-resource construct since OP doesn't close any of the used resources

Comment: @fantaghirocco - Good suggestion. I have added a link to Oracle's tutorial on it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a statement, use a `PreparedStatement`. Otherwise, [you get hacked](https://explainxkcd.com/327/).

More generally, JDBC is a tricky beast and not a particularly nice API. For fairly good reasons - it is designed to be the lowest common denominator, and it is more focused on exposing all the bells and whistles of all databases in existence, than in giving you, programmer who wants to interact with a database, a nice experience.

Try [JDBC](https://jdbc.org) or [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/).

Your exception handling is also wrong. If you catch an exception, either handle it, or make sure you throw something. Logging it, (or worse, printing it) **definitely does not count**. Add `throws` to your method signature. If that's not possible (and it usually is possible, try that first), `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e)` is what you want. not `e.printStackTrace()`, or even worse, what you did: You just tossed out **all** relevant information. Don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

I used this way and it is working greatly

- for iName

```
public void InsertQuery (String iName, String iType, int health_Problem, Date date2, String aRemind, String docName, String docType, String docAdress)
{
    final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ehealthdb?serverTimezone=UTC";
    final String DBUSER = "root";
    final String DBPSWD = "root";
    
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,DBUSER,DBPSWD);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        
        String iQuery = "INSERT into appointment" 
                        + "(ID, PatientID, Insurance_Name, Insurance_Type, Health_Problem, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Remind, Doctor_Name,Doctor_Type,Doctor_Adress)"
                        + "values ('1','1',,'"+iName+"','5','15.01.2020','1 Week','Musterarzt','Hausarzt','Musterstraße')";
        
        stmt.executeUpdate(iQuery);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong @InsertQuery");
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is unsafe. Do not concatenate values into a query string, it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead, use a prepared statement with parameters, as demonstrated by some of the other answers.